# EasyBCD Boot Device different to Windows Boot Manager device

Tags: multi-boot, grub2, bcdedit, easybcd, dualboot

Can someone explain why EasyBCD has a different Boot Device to the Windows Boot Manager device? My drives use MBR (not GPT).

BCDedit shows this at the beginning:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {4c702cd7-4348-11e9-a123-a126b58ebe81}
displayorder            {current}
                        {23a79a8c-7591-11e8-a5b9-10c37b6b0c8f}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30
```

and my PC always boots Drive 0 where Windows 10 resides.

BCDedit 2.4 shows this in brief:

```
Default: Windows 10
Timeout: 30 seconds
EasyBCD Boot Device: S:\

Entry #1
Name: Windows 10
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe

Entry #2
Name: Windows Server 2012 R2
BCD ID: {23a79a8c-7591-11e8-a5b9-10c37b6b0c8f}
Drive: S:\
Bootloader Path: \windows\system32\winload.exe
```

My problem is that after installing Ubuntu 19.10 on another drive, EasyBCD starts to cause real problems creating triple boot. It creates a NST folder on the S: drive and I think it also overwrites S:\windows\system32\winload.exe. EasyBCD does not even ask first if it may touch the S: drive (Disk 3). Obviously I don't want any changes on *Windows Server 2012 R2*, which I only use for testing and development.

I have repaired the S drive several times with the 3 bootrec commands! My Triple Boot only works directly in the BIOS (by selecting Boot Override usually).

Is there a better tool than EasyBCD, or - better still - does anyone know the BCDEDIT commands to create a third boot into Ubuntu 19.10 via /sdc (Disk 2)? This time I placed the GRUB2 bootloader also on /sdc (not on a partition of /sdc). Note: GRUB2 correctly boots Ubuntu and Windows 10 but doesn't see Windows Server. I'm fine with that but I want WBL to show me all three systems.

Comment: You might want to try "Visual BCD" https://www.boyans.net/ "Visual BCD Editor is an advanced graphical user interface (GUI) version of Windows bcdedit command line tool."

Comment: Sorry, but that site seems to be having difficutlies. A safe site to find alot of tools is "Major Geeks" https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/visual_bcd_editor.html

Comment: Windows boots from one drive and partition on that drive with boot flag. Second installs may overwrite that partition with its boot files & add second install to BCD. Grub2's os-prober only looks for Windows boot files, not boot flag. It is possible to change default drive or hide first drive, move boot flag to second Windows and repair it, so it has Windows boot files. Then you can directly boot either Windows from grub. Windows BIOS mode boot files, often in separate boot partition, but can be in main or c: partition: /bootmgr /Boot/BCD